# Method of characteristics for $f f_x + f_y = 1$. Where is the solution valid?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Suppose we have a PDE that can be solved with the method of characteristics

\begin{align}
F(\nabla u, u , x) = 0  \text{ in $U$}\\
u|_\Gamma = g \text{ on $\Gamma$ }
\end{align}

Where $\Gamma \subset \partial U$. Suppose the characteristic curves starting on $\Gamma$ don't span the whole set $U$, what can we say about the solution in this points outside the span? Do we lack information to solve the problem or can this be somehow avoided?

To have a precise example I solved the following problem,

$$f(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 1 \qquad\text{with}\qquad f(t,t) = \frac{t}{2} \quad\text{for}\quad 0 < t < 1.$$

In the above notation we have $\Gamma = \{(t,t):  0 < t < 1\}$ and $g(t) = t/2$. I got the solution $f(x,y) = z(s) + g(x(0)) =z(s) + \frac{x_0}{2} = y - \frac{x - 1/2y^2}{2-y}$ where $y \neq 2$, what can I say about the validity of my solution? Is it valid for $\mathbb{R^2}$ or just for points $x, y$ such that the characteristic curve trough them, $(x(s),y(s))$ lies on $\Gamma$ for $s=0$?

Answer (score 3):

This PDE is a non-homogeneous inviscid Burgers' equation. Let us apply the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics):

- $\frac{\text d y}{\text ds} = 1$, letting $y(0) = t$, we know $y = t + s$
- $\frac{\text d f}{\text ds} = 1$, letting $f(0) = t/2$, we know $f = t/2 + s$
- $\frac{\text d x}{\text ds} = f$, letting $x(0) = t$, we know $x = t + s(t + s)/2$

Therefore, the characteristics are the curves $x = t + y(y-t)/2$ for $0<t<1$, along which $f$ is given by
$$
f(x,y) = y - \frac{x-y^2/2}{2-y} \, .
$$
One can note that this expression is not defined at $y=2$, where the denominator vanishes. The solution is only valid over the domain in yellow
$$
(x,y) \in \lbrace (t + y(y-t)/2, y), 0<t<1, y<2\rbrace
$$

[image: characteristics]

Indeed, we start following characteristic curves at some point $(t,t)$ with $0<t<1$. On the one hand, we can decrease $y$ without restriction. But on the other hand, we cannot increase $y$ further than $y=2^-$. At the point $(x,y) = (2,2)$, all characteristic curves coming from $\lbrace(t,t), 0<t<1\rbrace$ intersect. The classical solution collapses (similar case to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454776/418542)).

---

The reason why the domain of validity is restricted to $y<2$ relates to the following Riccati ODE problem for $q = \partial_x f$:
$$
\tfrac{\text d q}{\text ds} = -q^2, \quad\text{letting}\quad q(0) = (t-2)^{-1}, \quad\text{we know}\quad q = (t+s-2)^{-1} ,
$$
which is derived from the initial PDE problem by partial differentiation with respect to $x$. The solution rewritten as $q(x,y) = \frac{1}{y-2}$ blows up at $y=2$ and cannot be used for larger times (even if the solution function is defined for $y>2$). See also the derivation by [Lax](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2551287), leading to Eq. (6.10) p. 36 of [(1)](http://www.acamedia.info/sciences/J_G/references/lax_1973.pdf).

[(1)](http://www.acamedia.info/sciences/J_G/references/lax_1973.pdf) P.D. Lax, *Hyperbolic systems of conservation laws and the mathematical theory of shock waves*, SIAM, 1973 [doi:10.1137/1.9781611970562.ch1](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611970562.ch1)

Comment: Why is the solution only valid on the domain in yellow when $f(x,y)$ is defined for all $x$, $y \neq 2$ ? It seems to me that the validity of the solution still holds outside although we might  lose unicity since the associated system of ODE does not have initial conditions.

Comment: I understand why the solution is not valid for $y =2$, I also see why the idea behind the method should fail if the characteristic curves intersect. But as I see it for $y>2$ the function $f(x,y)$ satisfies the pde and also the initial condition, so why can we not take it as a solution? Thanks a lot for the answer by the way.

Comment: I see! So the conclusion is that the solution still holds but we cannot guarantee uniqueness, right?

Comment: Sorry if im beeing too picky but I still don't get your point. The system of ODEs does have a solution by Picard-Lindelöf (even if it is not unique), since 1, 1 and $f$ are lipschitz, for any $[S, \infty)$, for some $S$ corresponding to $y >2$, so why are we losing existence? Also $f(x,y)$ satisfies the PDE everywhere where it is defined, and also the initial conditions. So how is $f$ not a solution? Could you maybe refer me somewhere were this is explained?

Comment: @h3h325 I'm troubled by your statement about Picard Lindelof, please note that it is a local existence *and* uniqueness theorem

Comment: @h3h325 i have edited the answer for clarity about the domain of validity. Please delete old comments.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 1 \tag 1$$
Charpit-Lagrange equations :
$$\frac{dx}{f}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{df}{1}$$
First family of characteristic curves, from $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{df}{1}$ :
$$f-y=c_1$$
Second family of characteristic curves, from $\frac{dx}{f}=\frac{df}{1}$ 
$$\frac12 f^2-x=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation :
$$\frac12 f^2-x=\Phi(f-y) \tag 2$$
Where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to boundary condition.

Condition : $f(x,x)=\frac{x}{2}$

$\frac12 (\frac{x}{2})^2-x=\Phi(\frac{x}{2}-x)\quad;\quad \frac{x^2}{8}-x=\Phi(-\frac{x}{2})$

Let $X=-\frac{x}{2}\quad;\quad x=-2X$

$ \frac{(-2X)^2}{8}-(-2X)=\Phi(X)$
$$\Phi(X)=\frac12 X^2+2X$$
So, the function $\Phi$ is determined. We put it into the general solution Eq.$(2)$ where $X=f-y$ :
$$\frac12 f^2-x=\frac12 (f-y)^2+2(f-y)$$
After simplification :
$$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2-4y+2x}{2y-4}\qquad y\neq 2.$$
This is the solution of the PDE which satisfies the boundary condition.

One can check that this solution is valid in putting it into the PDE.